# Numeros almacenados como texto cambiarlos a numero para realizar una suma (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estimados tengo que realizar una suma para obtener el resultado de un campo determinado sin embargo la columna que almacena estos datos, se encuentran como texto de la siguiente forma:

```
|Peso_Neto|
|22.55    |
|15.05    |
|12,06    |
```

intente utilizando la función Replace para cambiar puntos por comas, pero como se ve en el ejemplo hay algunos datos que si tienen coma por lo tanto me tira un error igual sl hacer la suma.

Agradezco la ayuda

PD: estoy en Sql-developer

Comment: Procura siempre incluir en tus preguntas, lo que dices que intentaste

Answer (score 2):

Hola amigo desconozco un poco de Oracle 
Segun como lo haría en SQL Server me quedaría algo así aquí te deje el ejemplo y como lo resolví.

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba(
    Peso_Neto VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Prueba (Peso_Neto) VALUES ('22.55');
INSERT INTO Prueba (Peso_Neto) VALUES ('12,06');
SELECT SUM(to_number(REPLACE(Peso_Neto,',','.'))) FROM Prueba
```

Primero remplazamos el ',' por '.' ya depues lo volvemos un numero el string y por ultimo realizamos la suma espero te sirva aquí donde lo realize.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9365701ad953f8eb8bc48d24a5c577d0